AKS Deploying an Nginx Load Balancer with TLS
I am very new to nginx and I am trying  to follow a docu to explain how to make a connection using nginx LB with TLS.
In theory, the procedure it is very simple:

Deploy Nginx LoadBalancer:

helm upgrade ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --install \
    --set controller.nodeSelector.starburstpool=base \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector.starburstpool=base \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector.starburstpool=base


Deploy Certificate Manager:

helm upgrade cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager --install --namespace certs-manager --create-namespace \
    --set installCRDs=true \
    --set nodeSelector.starburstpool=base \
    --set webhook.nodeSelector.starburstpool=base \
    --set cainjector.nodeSelector.starburstpool=base


Deploy Certificate Issuer:

Wait for the Certificate Manager to complete its deployment. Next, edit your local copy of cert-issuer.yaml. Add your email address to this file in the place indicated. After the file has been edited, run the following command:
The documentation said:
 - http01:
        ingress:
          class : nginx

But I change the class by public
$ cat cert-issuer.yaml 
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1

kind:   ClusterIssuer

metadata:
  name: letsencrypt

  namespace: certs-manager

  labels:
    name: letsencrypt
    iac: "Deployed-via-starburst-deploy"

spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: email@domain
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class : public
          podTemplate:
            spec:
              nodeSelector:
                "starburstpool": base

and then:
kubectl apply -f cert-issuer.yaml

Now I deploy my app.
$helm upgrade starburst-enterprise starburstdata/starburst-enterprise --install --values starburst.yaml \
    --set expose.type=ingress \
    --set expose.ingress.host=${starburst_url:?You need to specify a url}:443 \
    --set registryCredentials.username=${registry_usr:?Value not set} \
    --set registryCredentials.password=${registry_pwd:?Value not set} \
    --set sharedSecret="$(openssl rand 64 | base64)" \
    ....

But I see some issues:
$ kubectl get certificate
NAME                   READY   SECRET                 AGE
tls-secret-starburst   False   tls-secret-starburst   143m

The certificate is not ready
Describing the certificate
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:        2024-05-13T07:15:21Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         1
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      False
    Type:                        Ready
    Last Transition Time:        2024-05-13T07:15:21Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         1
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Issuing
  Next Private Key Secret Name:  tls-secret-starburst-qdg79
Events:                          <none>

But I have the secret
k describe secret tls-secret-starburst-qdg79
Name:         tls-secret-starburst-qdg79
Namespace:    clgroup
Labels:       cert-manager.io/next-private-key=true
              controller.cert-manager.io/fao=true
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
tls.key:  1704 bytes

If I review the challenge:
$ kubectl get challenge
NAME                                           STATE     DOMAIN            AGE
tls-secret-starburst-1-1114501067-2382483565   pending   pue.puetest.net   156m

$ kubectl describe challenge
....
Status:
  Presented:   true
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: wrong status code '503', expected '200'
  State:       pending
Events:        <none>

If I make a curl:
$ curl  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/350147985507
{
  "identifier": {
    "type": "dns",
    "value": "muDomain"
  },
  "status": "pending",
  "expires": "2024-05-20T07:15:22Z",
  "challenges": [
    {
      "type": "http-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/350147985507/cJzlaw",
      "token": "3gxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxIdkrit0"
    },
    {
      "type": "dns-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/350147985507/nyX5_A",
      "token": "3gxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxIdkrit0"
    },
    {
      "type": "tls-alpn-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/350147985507/IFP4fQ",
      "token": "3gxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxIdkrit0"
    }
  ]

So I don't know why all the challenge are pending.
I think that is the problems. But I don't know how to solve it.
